# Dataview row filter not working for update

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying top update LoginStatus but dataview is not filling data from datatable

```
if (datatable.Rows.Count > 0){
    DataView dView = new DataView(datatable);    
//in above statement datatable have some data but dview not filling    
    dView.RowFilter = "LoginStatus = 1";
}
```

Comment: try replace `DataView dView = new DataView(datatable);` with  `DataView view = datatable.DefaultView;`

Comment: i tried with DataView view = datatable.DefaultView; but same issue

Comment: Add more code. where are you binding your `DataTable`?

Comment: objVO.UserId = txtUserName.Value;
  objVO.Password = txtPassword.Value;
   datatable = objDAL.CheckUser(objVO);
            if (datatable.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                dView = new DataView(datatable);

                dView.RowFilter = "LoginStatus = 1";

Comment: In objDAL.CheckUser(objVO) returning datatable fine but issue with DataView dView = new DataView(datatable);   and   i tried with  dView =datatable.DefaultView;

Comment: OK.. does it give any exception at `DataView dView=new DataView(datatable)`?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe instead of throwing the whole datatable at the dataview, try adding single row at a time.

```
 foreach (DataRow row in datatable)
 {
   dView.AddNew(row);
 }
```

Comment: Sebastian, your answer assumes that dataTable is a DataSet. From the name, it seems it's a DataTable. DataTable does not have a Tables property.